# Type mismatch solved without editing VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a budgetting spreadsheet with a bunch of macros that are used to manipulate sheets and data. It all works fine. For some reason after saving a new version, one of the macros "Add Discount" comes up with a Type Mismatch error. I analysed the code, couldn't find a problem, then went back to a previous build that was working, and it had exactly the same code. The weird thing is that the solution I have found to work is to cut and repaste the code in the module (i.e. no modifications to the code, just delete and repaste).

I am using Mac though I don't know if that is a factor. It has happened twice already in the last couple of months and I don't know why! Does anyone know what can cause this and how to prevent it?

I've editted the code to get rid of superflous stuff. The line provoking the Type Mismatch in debug was

```
For Each sh In Worksheets(arrShts)
```

Many thanks

```
Sub AddDiscount()

Dim lineCode As String
Dim arrShts As Variant
Dim row As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rngS As Range, rngD As Range, totalCell As Range, totalSection As Range, discountSection As Range
Dim cell As Range, formla As Range

lineCode = Selection.EntireRow.Cells(, 1).Value
row = Selection.row
arrShts = Array("Control", "Budget", "OT", "WD", "CdA")

'Proceed with line item discount...
If lineCode = "L" Then
    For Each sh In Worksheets(arrShts)
        sh.Rows(row + 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, _
                                CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        sh.Rows(row + 1).ClearComments
        sh.Rows(row + 1).FormatConditions.Delete
        sh.Rows(row).EntireRow.Copy sh.Rows(row + 1).EntireRow
    Next sh

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have You tried: `For Each sh In Worksheets(arrShts).Cells` ?

Comment: I tried the minimal code on Excel 2007 and got no error. However, when the array has a non-existent sheet name, I get an "Subscript out of range" error on the For Each statement.

Comment: @Teamothy Thanks for the reply. I have not tried that modification. Do you think it will help with the random "Type mismatch" error? As I said, the code works 99% of the time, but sometimes when I save a new build, it stops working until I repaste the identical code!

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks for trying. Yes as I say, the code works fine 99% of the time which is why I am puzzled. Also I have tried the same file which gives the error on Excel for Windows and it is fine. just Excel for Mac (version 16.29 currently) which gives the error occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the code and it works like a charm. The only thing that pops to my mind (besides being a Mac issue) is that the user has set the focus on another `Workbook` and that generates the error (because it can't find those `Sheets` ofc).

Try to specify the `Workbook` name and see if you get any results:

```
For Each sh In Workbooks("My workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(arrShts)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Louis. Again do you think it will help with the random "Type mismatch" error? As I said, the code works 99% of the time. I suspect it's a Mac thing. Excel for Mac is a bit buggy from my experience and especially problematic when running more complex VBA etc. I was wondering if there was something in my syntax that could be improved or known to cause problems!

Comment: You're welcome. The only time something similar happened to me, was because the user was switching workbook while executing the macro and specifying the name helped me solving the issue. Of course, I cannot guarantee you that it'll work on Mac, but it's worth the shot. :)